# Simplify dataframe by combining data from various columns together for same instance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe after concatenting several dataframes

```
df1 = 
        instance              scan        comp         sort
0       A                    23:15:12      NaN         NaN
1       B                    23:17:12      NaN         NaN
2       C                    23:16:12      NaN         NaN

0       A                    NaN           23:19:32    NaN 
1       B                    NaN           23:19:32    NaN 
2       C                    NaN           23:43:23    NaN

0       A                    NaN           NaN         23:45:32
1       B                    NaN           NaN         23:45:26
2       C                    NaN           NaN         23:45:12
```

I need to simplify above and have all the columns for the same instance to be updated

```
df2 = 
  instance              scan        comp         sort
       A                23:15:12    23:19:32  23:45:32
       B                23:17:12    23:19:32  23:45:26
       C                23:16:12    23:43:23  23:45:12
```

There can 100's of such instances and many columns for each instance such as scan, comp,sort etc. I have tried groupby(['instance'), but it doesnt seem to work and resulting in object errors.
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f72f595f650>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`groupby_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html):

```
df2 = df1.groupby('instance', as_index=False).first()
print(df2)

# Output
  instance      scan      comp      sort
0        A  23:15:12  23:19:32  23:45:32
1        B  23:17:12  23:19:32  23:45:26
2        C  23:16:12  23:43:23  23:45:12
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html), the function returns:

> First non-null of values within each group.

Maybe I'm wrong but IIUC, your dataframes (before `pd.concat`) should look like:

```
>>> df1
  instance      scan
0        A  23:15:12
1        B  23:17:12
2        C  23:16:12

>>> df2
  instance      comp
0        A  23:19:32
1        B  23:19:32
2        C  23:43:23

>>> df3
  instance      sort
0        A  23:45:32
1        B  23:45:26
2        C  23:45:12
```

So you can use `pd.merge` instead of `pd.concat` with `reduce` function from `functools` module:

```
from functools import reduce

out = reduce(lambda left, right: left.merge(right, on='instance', how='outer'),
             [df1, df2, df3])
print(out)

# Output
  instance      scan      comp      sort
0        A  23:15:12  23:19:32  23:45:32
1        B  23:17:12  23:19:32  23:45:26
2        C  23:16:12  23:43:23  23:45:12
```

Comment: Genius ..Exacttly what I need. THanks a lot for your answer support..It works like a charm !!

Comment: Your answer worked for me like a charm!!Sorry about that..I thought I can accept both answers, apparently stack overflow doesnt allow that.. I accepted this answer..

Comment: Your enthousiasm is communicative, you make my day, Corralien's anwers are a little bit unconventional so interesting, and then I forgive you  ... for your rigth choice :)

Answer (score 2):

Other solution :

```py
(df1.groupby('instance', group_keys=True)
    .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
    .drop_duplicates('instance')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    )
```

```
  instance      scan      comp      sort
0        A  23:15:12  23:19:32  23:45:32
1        B  23:17:12  23:19:32  23:45:26
2        C  23:16:12  23:43:23  23:45:12
```

**group_keys**

In the provided sample, the `group_keys` parameter has no effect because each row in the `instance` column contains a unique key. When there is only one key per group, setting `group_keys=True` or `group_keys=False` will have the same result.

If you want to avoid grouping the keys when there are multiple identical keys and keep each row as a separate group, you can set `group_keys=False` explicitly. This can be useful when you want to preserve the original order and structure of the DataFrame.

Comment: Why not simply `df.groupby('instance', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates('instance')`? Does it work for you?

Comment: It works too, fact is that I just want to silent the warning. Message from interpreter : `To adopt the future behavior and silence this warning, use 

 >>> .groupby(..., group_keys=True)`